# Check if there is a cookie on the client machine, otherwise you do something and exit

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

The text of the exercise is this:
"Write a web application that creates an electronic survey page for choosing one of five candidates for mayors. The application must include the setting of a cookie to register the vote on the machine of clients that have already expressed their preference. If the machine from which the client connects does NOT contain the vote registration cookie, the user is admitted to the voting page, otherwise the user must be automatically redirected to a statistics page that displays the percentage of votes acquired by the five candidates."

How can I check if a cookie already exists on the client machine?
I tried so but rightly from the html file I make the first vote, enter the if and so it stops, but it's not good because it would be the first vote and NOT the second.
HELP !!

```
public class SerElection extends HttpServlet{
  int cGhezzi=0, cPelliccia=0, cValente=0, cBussi=0, cFerri=0;

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException{
    String candid = request.getParameter("candidato");
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(candid,candid);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    String c = cookie.getName();
    if(c.equals("Ghezzi") || c.equals("Pelliccia") || c.equals("Valente") || c.equals("Bussi") || c.equals("Ferri")){
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
      out.println("<title></title>");
      out.println("</head>");
      out.println("<body>");
      out.println("<h3>I'm sorry but you've already voted</h3>");
      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");
      out.close();
    }
else{
      //ACCORDING TO THE CHOICE OF CHOICE INCREMENT ITS VARIABLE FOR STATISTICS
      if(candid.equals("Ghezzi")) cGhezzi++;
      if(candid.equals("Pelliccia")) cPelliccia++;
      if(candid.equals("Valente")) cValente++;
      if(candid.equals("Bussi")) cBussi++;
      if(candid.equals("Ferri")) cFerri++;
      //response.sendRedirect("/Elezioni/index.html");
  } //END ELSE
.
.
.
```

Comment: @Mischiefz no! I have to see if a cookie is already present on the client, in which case it exits, otherwise it votes and exits

Comment: @Mischiefz can you help me??

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is use the link and get the cookie with

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
```

as

```
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

is used to set the cookie, then check if not `null`, so you know whether voter voted or not. If `not null` and getName set as the votedName, you can then redirect the user out.

But do know this cookies can be modified or cleared by mostly all browsers or there might be issues when the browser wont support cookies.

This is just a rough answer, so feel free to edit

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
Boolean notVoted = true; //flag to see if user voted
if (cookies != null) { //check if cookie exist
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        String c = cookie.getName();
        if(c.equals("Ghezzi") || c.equals("Pelliccia") || c.equals("Valente") || c.equals("Bussi") || c.equals("Ferri")){
          response.setContentType("text/html");
          notVoted = false; //if user voted and cookie verifies then set flag
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          out.println("<html>");
          out.println("<head>");
          out.println("<title></title>");
          out.println("</head>");
          out.println("<body>");
          out.println("<h3>I'm sorry but you've already voted</h3>");
          out.println("</body>");
          out.println("</html>");
          out.close();
        }
    }
}
else if(notVoted){ //in case no cookies and user has not voted
    // do the voting stuff here
    String candid = request.getParameter("candidato");// set the cookie after user voted
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(candid,candid);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The problem is that as soon as I make the FIRST vote it gives me that I have already voted because rightly the cookie is created and it recognizes it immediately as soon as it enters the first if.

Comment: its probably because u set the cookie using `response.addCookie(cookie);` and then immediately use the same cookie to check if the user voted using `String c = cookie.getName();` note: 1 line above you set it as the cadidate name and next line you check if the cookie has a vote info, so your first `if `is always `true`